# error in fetch array - CRUD PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am doing a PHP CRUD with mysql and I came across an error that I am already trying for hours and can not solve, can anyone help me?

The error that is being displayed is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array () on string in C:
>   \ wamp \ www \ crud_oop \ index.php on line 233

line 233 is in the while close_array, the funny thing is that the first item in the table appears normally, but the rest does not,
I have other blocks of code above all in the same style but all are working normally, only this one gave error

```
<div class="container">
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
<div class="well" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding:auto; width:70%;">
    <span style="font-size:25px; color:#1f1a2f"><strong>Sorteio</strong></span> <!-- BOTÕES -->
    <span class="pull-right"><a href="#addnewPe" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Adicionar</a></span>
    <div style="height:15px;"></div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Data pedido</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Funcionário</th>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Total do pedido</th>
        <th>Ação</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM tb_pedido Pp INNER JOIN tb_cliente C ON Pp.codCliente = C.codCliente INNER JOIN tb_funcionario F ON Pp.codFuncionario = F.codFuncionario INNER JOIN tb_produto P ON Pp.codProduto = P.codProduto");
        while($row=$query->fetch_array()){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['codPedido']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['dataPedido']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nomeCliente']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nomeFuncionario']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['descricao']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['qtdVendida']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['totalPedido']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <span class="pull-center"><a href="#delPp<?php echo $row['codPedido']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></span>
                    <p>_____</p>
                    <span class="pull-center"><a href="#editPp<?php echo $row['codPedido']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></span>
                    <?php include('pedido/button.php'); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }

        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['msgPp'])){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['msgPp']; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        unset($_SESSION['msgPp']);
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php include('pedido/add_modal.php'); ?>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: are you using mysql or mysqli?

Comment: i'm using mysqli

Comment: Try like this while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

Comment: what are the contents of `pedido/button.php`, hope it doesn't override value of `$query` variable?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in 

This was the error you gave when I put the code you requested

Comment: on the btn this is the code:
this is the part that uses the query

<?php
     $del=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tb_pedido where codPedido='".$row['codPedido']."'");
     $drow=mysqli_fetch_array($del);
    ?>

Comment: I just saw here that your solution worked out, the only problem is that it is not showing all the rows of the table, please do not give up on me kkk

Answer (score -1):

Always check for errors when running a query.

```
$sql=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM tb_pedido Pp INNER JOIN tb_cliente C ON Pp.codCliente = C.codCliente INNER JOIN tb_funcionario F ON Pp.codFuncionario = F.codFuncionario INNER JOIN tb_produto P ON Pp.codProduto = P.codProduto");

$res = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");

        while($row=$res->fetch_array()){
```

Comment: I'm sorry friend but I did not understand your answer ... I'm a beginner in PHP

Comment: now i have 2 problems
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in
and
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in

Comment: accept ans close this query, and post second one to solve.